# Dealing with multiple cursors in cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cursor, cx-oracle

While my task is relatively simple: take data from one table in schema A, and insert in into another table in schema B, I'm stuck on how to do this in cx_Oracle.

In PL/SQL I would do something along the lines of:

INSERT INTO Schema_B.Table
...
FROM Schema_A.Table.

However, in cx_Oracle I have a separate cursor for each connection, and have no clue how to connect to both schemas in one SQL statement. Can attach my code if needed.

Essentialy, I have something of the sort:

```
connect_db_1 = cx_Oracle_database.connect(db 1 credentials)
connect_db_2 = cx_Oracle_database.connect(db 2 credentials)

schema 1 =...
schema 2=...

cursor_db_1 = connect_db_1.cursor()
cursor_db_2 = connect_db_2.cursor()

#sample statement that works on one database
cursor_db_1.execute(F'select * from {schema_1}.table.a)
```

However, if I need to select something from one database, then put it into the other with one statement, I have no clue how to do that, since it required both cursors to be used

```
cursor_db_1.execute(F'insert into {schema_2}.table_1
                    SELECT * from {schema_1}.table.a )
```

This doesn't work, since once of the schemas is not in this cursor

Comment: If the tables are in the same database, then using a SQL statement or PL/SQL block will be fastest because data won't need to be transferred over the network to (and from) Python.  You seem to have the SQL statement already.  Can you update your question with more details about the problem?  Showing code is always wise on StackOverflow.

Comment: It's kind of an experiment to use Python for this, a "proof of statement, so to say"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to insert into another DB, or another user in the same DB?

If it's another DB, then something will have to connect to both DBs: either in cx_Oracle with two connections, or from one database to the other using a [DB link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793).  If you use cx_Oracle with two connections, then tune [arraysize](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance) when querying, and use [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) when inserting.

If your users are in the same DB, then you can use GRANT to give appropriate permissions to the writing user so it can read the other user's table.

Comment: I am trying to insert into another database

Comment: Explore the DB link option, since this is likely to be efficient.  If you want/must use cx_Oracle, then look at the examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples).  Use one connection to get data to Python data structures, and then use the second connection to insert with executeMany() to the other DB.  Your actual code will depend on the data types.